# Building blocks of event-driven architecture

Tags: design-patterns, pipeline, event-driven

In pipeline processing of data, we use,

- Generator(s)
- Intermediate processor engine(s)(Aggregate operations)
- Terminator(s)

For example, using python generator & co-routines,

### [image]

&

### [image]

&

### [image]

---

Can **Generator(s)**-**IntermediateProcessor(s)**-**Terminator(s)** be considered as building blocks of [event-driven-architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

What your event-driven-architecture is missing is the events.  As long as all of your modules (generators, terminators, etc) can both receive and send events to their desired recipients, it is an event driven architecture.

Occasionally, you'll get very similar to event-driven-architecture like pipelines, but the information being passed is not considered an event.  For example, the Java lambda streams are passing along Data, not events.

Now, if one decided to call all of their data elements "events" then one could argue it was event driven; but, that argument would die quickly as events often have a structure (or at least a type) that doesn't mutate through the stream's processing stages.

With this small idea in mind.  Yes, all means of processing events originate at a source (generators), go through processing nodes that might fully consume the event (terminators), or go through nodes that might generate other events (intermediate processors).

However, this classification is yours, and is not a requirement of an event-processing system.  For example, I could have nodes that act in multiple of these roles.  A single node might terminate "employee-quits" events for an employee that already had their termination handled, while doing some work and forwarding a "removeFromPayroll" event to accounting for an employee that has not had their termination handled.  Likewise, an event to schedule a daily email reminder is not fully a "generator" but takes on many of the aspects of a "generator".

So your classification is fine, provided that you realize it is a classification that you are adding to a system to help you organize it, and not a rigid set of "node types" which are exclusive.

---- Example ----

A better example of what you would be talking about would be

```
(origin) -> follow_news_topic -> (story web spider) -> new_news_topic_article -> (archiver)
```

Here we can clearly see that there are two events "follow_news_topic" and "new_news_topic_article"

The "event orientation" is the focus on the events.  The nodes are generalized elements, but they are not quite general enough to cleanly fit into one of your 3 classifications.  A node might pull double-duty (or even triple-duty) under your classification.

Comment: Most of the event-driven architectures execute around processing content from `.evt`(in windows) or `/var/log`( in linux) or `access.log`( of webserver). I know, CA NSM & CA Spectrum are some of these products, who does this job. Here,  every event message is data and nothing more than that. isn't it? So, am still not clear, when you say *missing is the events*.

Comment: @overexchange Generally the event has a bit more than just the data, so it can be interpreted correctly in the new event handler.  In some languages, the "type" of the event (Java's Swing Events for example) add extra data which permits the event to be understood better.  Other events are structured records, so the data is better understood at the other end of the line.  For example, it would not make any sense to push "integers" as events when dealing with Cartesian coordinates, because you'd never assure that x and y are received in a context that is unambiguous.

Comment: Extra data in events of Java Swing? I think there are some UI events, shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)#User_generated_events) or [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Front-end-programming/blob/master/4_Javascript_Programming/Topic8_DOM_Access/DOM_interface_hierarchy.png) that has it's own `actionPerformed`. Is this what  you meant by understanding the event better?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, extra data.  All of the events share a base "event" class, but the mouse event has information about which mouse buttons are pressed, the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer, and the "type" of MouseEvent.  On the other hand, another Swing "event", has a "type" of KeyboardEvent, and lacks X and Y coordinate data, but contains key press events.  There's "MouseDragged" events, "WindowMoved" events, etc. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/package-use.html has a lot of events.  No two are quite the same (they at least differ by class type).

Comment: Hmm... For processing such events, I wrote some code, [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Design_pattern/tree/master/EventHandling-Observer_pattern). Can you suggest a better design pattern for processing such different types of events?